# Remove duplicate items in a std::list

Tags: c++

I have a list of string, how can I remove the duplicate value in a std::list, like

```
std::list<std::string> listName;

listName.push_back("Foo");
listName.push_back("Bar");
listName.push_back("Foo");
```

Then I want to remove the duplicate name which is "Foo". And remaining is only "Bar" name.

Thanks!

Comment: @DyP: The OP wants all instances of duplicated items removed (i.e. if "foo" appears twice, ALL "foo"s are to be removed. `list::unique()` won't do that)

Answer (score 2):

If you want only unique elements in `listName` you could do:

```
listName.sort();  
listName.unique();
```

listName should remain: `"Foo", "Bar"`

If you want to get rid of all elements have duplicate, you could use `std::list::sort` to sort elements, then use `std::adjacent_find` to find duplicate elements.

```
listName.sort();   

std::list<std::string>::iterator ab = std::adjacent_find(listName.begin(), listName.end());
if (ab != listName.end())  // if duplicate elements are found
{
    std::list<std::string>::iterator ae = std::upper_bound(listName.begin(), listName.end(), *ab);  // try to locate last occurrence 
    if (std::distance(ab, ae) > 1)
    {
        listName.erase(ab, ae); // remove all dup elements
    }
}
```

listName remain: `"Bar"`

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) fore more `std::list` inerface

Comment: The OP has indicated that only "Bar" remains. This would also have "Foo".

Comment: I just did that approach and it was wrong as OP wants `And remaining is only "Bar" name.`

Comment: People need to read the question more carefully, and stop recommending `list::unique()` :)

Comment: My mistake.  Given the performance of `std::upper_bound` on a Bidirectional iterator (log comparisons, but linear searches), it might be easier to search forward linearly.  Or at least start the search at the found iterator, and not begin().

Comment: I think you can replace `std::distance(ab, ae) > 1` with `std::next(ab) != ae`.

Comment: @DyP how about if there are a few dups?

Comment: @billz Not sure what you mean. `std::distance(ab, ae) > 1` (note the `>1`) should be equivalent to `std::next(ab) != ae`, as the list is sorted and `upper_bound` returns the next element which is *greater* than the passed value, or the second argument if there's no such.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to use a `std::map` instead of a `list`. The map will store the strings and keep a count of how many times they occur. The only real change to your code is you need to use `++` instead of `push_back` to put the string in the map;

```
std::map<std::string, int> listName;
++listName["Foo"];
++listName["Bar"];
++listName["Foo"];
```

Then to remove entries with a count greater than 1:

```
for (auto it = listName.begin(); it != listName.end(); )
{
    if (it->second > 1)
        listName.erase(it++);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list, then you can easily find the duplicates.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> listName = {"Foo", "Bar", "Foo", "Foobar"};

    listName.sort();

    for(auto i = listName.begin(); i != listName.end(); )
    {
        auto range = std::equal_range(i, listName.end(), *i);

        if(std::next(range.first) != range.second)
            i = listName.erase(range.first, range.second);
        else ++i;
    }

    for(auto const& e : listName) std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

Shortest version I could come up with, but iterates twice over each element to be deleted (once in `equal_range`, and once during `erase`).

Alternatively, iterating once over each element:

```
    listName.sort();

    for(auto i = listName.begin(); i != listName.end(); )
    {
        auto j = std::next(i);
        bool duplicate = false;

        while(j != listName.end() && *j == *i)
        {
            duplicate = true;
            j = listName.erase(j);
        }

        if(duplicate) i = listName.erase(i);

        i = j;
    }
```

As an exercice, moving `duplicate = true` out of the loop:

```
    listName.sort();

    for(auto i = listName.begin(); i != listName.end(); )
    {
        auto j = std::next(i);
        bool duplicate = (j != listName.end() && *j == *i);

        if(duplicate)
        {
            do
            {
                j = listName.erase(j);
            }while(j != listName.end() && *j == *i);

            listName.erase(i);
        }

        i = j;
    }
```